# Error iterating over a list of values in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to iterate over a list in Helm3, in order to create several namespaces in one template file.

values.yaml

```
namespace:
  - dev
  - vv
```

templates/namespaces.yaml

```
{{- range .Values.namespace }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: {{ . | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

However when I try to `helm install . -f values.yaml` I get the following error:

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Secret.metadata.namespace): invalid type for io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta.namespace: got "array", expected "string"
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note, the `-` in the last line removes the newline at the end of this YAML block.  There's an extra newline at the beginning of the block (before the `---`) so this loop in isolation works out, but you might look at the `helm template . -f values.yaml` output and see if that's a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the error does not relate to the templates/namespaces.yaml but to some other template (secret). Probably the `namespace` from the `values.yaml` overrides a value with the same name from the default `values.yaml`. Try renaming it, e.g. `namespaces`.